# IF statement error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a paid program that I'm trying to promote and I'm trying to send a block of content within an email only to the customers who don't have it active.
I wrote this if statement but I'm getting an error and I don't know why?

```
%%[

        set @WSubscriptionProgram = Lookup("Subscribed Customers","IsActive","CustomerID", @CustomerID)
        set @SubscriptionData = Lookup("Subscribed Customers","CustomerID","CustomerID", @CustomerID)

        if ((@SubscriptionData == @CustomerID) AND (@WSubscriptionProgram == 'False')) OR NOT EMPTY(@SubscriptionData)) then

        ]%%

        %%[ /* Menu */ ]%% %%=ContentBlockByID("8605")=%%

        %%[

        else 

        /* Do Not Show Any Content */

        endif

]%%
```

Comment: Which is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few things that I see here:

1. You don't declare where `@CustomerID` comes from
2. I don't understand why you would check this condition, as this will always be true since it comes from the lookup used: `@SubscriptionData == @CustomerID` - or did I misunderstand?
3. Is `@WSubscriptionProgram` a mandatory field? If yes, then it will never be empty and the second condition will also always resolve to true

Try something like this instead:

```
%%[
set @CustomerID = _subscriberkey
set @WSubscriptionProgram = Lookup("Subscribed Customers","IsActive","CustomerID", @CustomerID)
set @SubscriptionData = Lookup("Subscribed Customers","CustomerID","CustomerID", @CustomerID)

if @WSubscriptionProgram == 'False' OR NOT EMPTY(@SubscriptionData) then

]%% 

%%=ContentBlockByID("8605")=%%

%%[endif]%%
```

To make above more lean, you could use [LookupRows()](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/) if you're fetching all the data from the same DE.

Additionally, you're saying:

> I'm trying to send an email only to the customers who don't have it
>   active.

Including AMPscript in the email won't prevent it from being sent to everyone - it will just display content based on the conditions that are defined. If you actually only need to send it to people who don't have a subscription, then just filter the list you're using.